# Save JSON provided from REST API to local file on android

Tags: android, json, rest

I'm creating an app that connects via internet to a rest API which is connect to a postgres database.

In this API I am exporting some JSON data that I wish to consume using the app. I pretend on using okhttp3 to do this.
The thing is, I wan't this JSON data to be available locally, and be downloaded to the persons phone since the app is mostly going to be used underground, inside subway stations, where there is no internet connection.

My question is how can I get the data that return from the REST API, and persisti it to a JSON file and then deserialize it as needed to show the data to the user.

I pretend on using GSON to deserialize, but I don't know how to save the data to a file and, after that, acess that data.

Also I pretend on implementing a automatic update system where, after any change on the data, the app will be able to download and overwrite the old data with the updated version.

Also I'm using Java, not Kotlin, for this app.

Comment: you can use retrofit as network client to get your json .... i suggest you to use room database for offline use

Comment: So the best approach should be retrieve the data from the rest api, serialize it into a room entities and save it to a room database?

Comment: Yes @ChristianW.A.Hess, That is the best and optimized option available for such situation. If you use Room, it anyway saves in a database file.